# Exception occurred calling method NotesDocumentCollection.putAllInFolder(string)

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I am getting the following error while copying more than 17000 documents to a folder:

```
Exception occurred calling method NotesDocumentCollection.putAllInFolder(string)
```

This is my code:

```
docColl = database.search(formula);
getComponent("TempName").setValue(docColl.getCount());
docColl.putAllInFolder("f_Statistics");
```

If I move less than 17000 documents, it works. There is nothing to with no of documents in the view.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check the XPages log file for more details on the exception.

Comment: Does it always fail on the same document? Are there documents with reader/author fields? Is there enough disk space on the destination server?

Comment: Are there responses in the collection and the folder has "Show documents in response hierarchy" enabled?

Comment: ~17k is so close to max value of 2 byte word, that it seems to be some internal limit of API. Try mentioned solutions to batch it in smaller chunks.

Comment: As Tode wrote: Please check if there are any response documents in your collection. And check or post the stacktrace of your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can use a loop and a try... catch to handle the error. I'm not sure about the exact syntax you would need for xpages, but could be something like this:

```
docColl = database.search(formula);
exceptionCaught = true;  // little white lie
while(exceptionCaught = true);
{

  getComponent("TempName").setValue(docColl.getCount());
  exceptionCaught = false;
  try
  {
    docColl.putAllInFolder("f_Statistics");
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {  // It blew up; assume that this means there were too many docs
     View folder = db.getView("f_Statistics");
     docColl.Subtract(folder.getAllEntries();
     exceptionCaught = true;
  }
}
```

Yes, it's a hack.

And no... the above is not tested, or even syntax checked.  I'm just throwing out the idea.

If you try this, I strongly recommend that you do some additional checking to make sure that the cause of the exception really is the number of docs, because if any other exception occurs, the above code will most likely be an infinite loop!

Answer (score 1):

> How can I solve this problem?

Copy fewer documents? Whty not split it up into multiple moves if you are having problems when the number of documents exceede a certain number?

Comment: Thanks you for reply Karl:- I dont have any idea to split the document collection . Are you saying about looping every documents? or any other idea? if i have 30000 docs , it is moving approximately 17000 docs , after that only it is throwing the error.

Comment: @Vijayakumar Perhaps you could loop through the documents in the collection instead of trying to do it all at once.

Comment: Vijayakumar: As David suggests, loop through the collection and move the documents to the folder one by one. Or build multiple smaller collection (perhaps by year created or some other field on the documents). There are several ways to handle this.

Comment: I did looping. But i cannot move even single document. `if(@Trim(formula)!=""){   
   var docColl:NotesDocumentCollection=database.search(formula);
   var docCount=docColl.getCount()
   getComponent("TempCount").setValue(docCount); 
   print("docCount="+docCount)
   for(i=1;i<=docCount;i++){
    var doc:NotesDocument=docColl.getNthDocument(i);   
    print("i="+i)
    doc.putInFolder("f_Statistics")
   }
  } It throws the following error -> `HTTP JVM: docCount=30608
i=1
Error in getStatistics: Exception occurred calling method NotesDocument.putInFolder(string)
null ` Please help me.

Comment: @Vijayakumar: Please check if the document is a response document. And post the full stack trace in your question.

Comment: No response documents. Everything is document.Show response documents in hierarchy option is enabled. If it is small number of documents, working fine. if it is morethan 17k docs , we cannot even move one document. is there any restriction that document collection has? Any possiblity to 32 k?

Comment: I am not sure if SSJS works the same as Lotusscript/Java, but I would NOT use GetNthDocument, to start with.
The error sounds like doc does not have a value. Try to use GetFirstDocument/GetNextDocument to loop through the view. You also might need a temporary variable to store the doc before you use GetNextDocument(), and then use that variable to move the document to the folder after you get the next document.

Comment: I know it may simply be due to the cut and paste, but I'm not seeing semi-colons where I think the lines are supposed to end, such as 
    var docCount=docColl.getCount() getComponent("TempCount").setValue(docCount);

Comment: Thanks for all of you . It helped me lot. Karl-Henry Martinsson : that is worked.

Comment: Thanks for all your tips.Recently I faced the same issue in another application. instead of putting all documents at one shot , i did looping and given the exception handling in that particular line. The problem was replication or saved conflicts documents not moving. I had to skip that document and moved. Thanks to Sven Hasselback , Karl-Hentry , Richard and Pen Henrick.